# Asana API Returning Unexpected Results

Tags: api, asana

I'm trying to return completed tasks from the Asana API since a given date, but am getting back both complete and incomplete tasks.

Here's the request I'm making:

... @app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace='+wkspce+'&completed_since='+computedDate+'&assignee=me&opt_fields=due_on,name,projects,tags,completed_at'

Any idea what I've done wrong

Answer (score 0):

The `completed_since` parameter is a slight misnomer: it always includes incomplete tasks as well. It was originally intended as a way to get only tasks that are currently relevant - basically, a way to skip all the tasks that were completed ages ago (as a replacement for the old "archive" feature), so that for large projects you don't have to always fetch the *entire* thing.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - I guess I missed that in the documentation. This makes a lot more sense.